# gulp-babel doesn't transpile from node_modules

Tags: gulp, babeljs, gulp-concat, gulp-babel

I noticed that gulp-babel doesn't transpile my code from node_modules, only from src folder. I have the latest version of node and npm. Here are my setup.

`.babelrc`

```
{
    "presets": [
        ["@babel/preset-env", {
            "modules": false
        }]
    ]
}
```

`package.json`

```
"@babel/core": "^7.11.1",
"@babel/preset-env": "^7.11.0",
"browser-sync": "^2.26.10",
"gulp": "^4.0.2",
"gulp-babel": "^8.0.0",
"gulp-concat": "^2.6.1",
```

`gulpfile.js`

```
gulp.task('compile:core', function (done) {
    return gulp
        .src('./node_modules/fetch-inject/dist/fetch-inject.js')
        .pipe(babel())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.temp.js))
    done();
});

// Compile JS file
gulp.task('compile:js', function (done) {
    return gulp
        .src('./src/js/app.js')
        .pipe(babel())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.temp.js))
    done();
});
```

For testing purposes I put the same code into both app.js and fetch-inject.js files. `compile:core` didn't transpile the code only `js`.
It seems because it's in node_modules folder. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out node_modules transpile only works if I use `babel.config.json`